# JasperReports: Show line between two enteries, but not after the last record

Tags: jasper-reports

I an using *JasperReports* to download some content in *pdf* format. I fetched some data from the database and add a *textField* in the *Detail* band to show the entries of a particular column.

This is what I am getting

[image]

and if I add a line than *pdf* changed to

[image]

but my requirement is to show line between two entries.

I want to remove last line and the *pdf* should looks like

[image]

Comment: Could you care to share some code on how are you adding line and text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the line at the top of the detail band instead of the bottom, then change the *printWhenExpression* to `$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() != 1`.

The line will then be printed before each entry except for the first one, essentially putting a line between each entry.